# как создать telegram группу автоматически

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Для создания telegram бота использую aiogram, нужно что бы бот создал группу и добавил туда людей. Или как то автоматизировать это по другому. Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью библиотеки `Pyrogram`. В документации [есть метод](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/messages/create-chat) `createChat()`.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("123", api_id=1234567, api_hash="abcdef12345679890abcdef1234567890")

@app.on_message(filters.command('create', prefixes="."))
def create(_, msg):
    ids = [12345678, 12345678] #Айди пользователей, которые будут добавлены
    app.createChat(ids, "имя группы")
app.run()
```

Получить `api_id` и `api_hash` можно [здесь](https://my.telegram.org/apps) (необходимо авторизоваться, написать номер телефона вашего основного аккаунта, и ввести код из Telegram, создать приложение и скопировать `api_id` и `api_hash`)

Во время первого запуска кода, программа опять запросит номер телефона и код, который отправит вам Telegram, но не бойтесь, это официальная процедура. После введите куда нибудь команду `.create`, например в избранное.

Comment: да, pyrogram подходит, но видимо из-за обновлений там другой синтаксис. Группа создается с помощью pyrogram.raw.functions.messages.create_chat.CreateChat()